# Qt/C++ - Unable to post text inputs and upload a file

Tags: c++, qt

This is my code in Qt.

```
void UploadPatch(QString archive)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    qInfo() << "Upload procedure started! This could take a while, please wait....";
    QUrl url("https://www.test.test/api/upload/newVersion");
    QNetworkRequest request(url);

    #ifdef DEVELOPMENT_ENV
        QSslConfiguration sslConfig = request.sslConfiguration();
        sslConfig.setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone);
        sslConfig.setProtocol(QSsl::TlsV1_2); // Adjust the protocol as needed
        request.setSslConfiguration(sslConfig);
    #endif

    // Set headers
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------BOUNDARY");
    request.setRawHeader("accept", "application/json");
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization", "Bearer TOKEN_HERE");

    // Create a multipart POST request
    QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

    // Add text parameters
    QStringList params = {"os", "major", "minor", "patch", "build"};
    QStringList values = {"mac", "2", "2", "2", "100"};

    for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); ++i) {
        QHttpPart textPart;
        textPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, "form-data; name=\"" + params[i] + "\"");
        textPart.setBody(values[i].toUtf8());
        multiPart->append(textPart);
    }

    // Add file parameter using QFile as the body
    QHttpPart filePart;
    filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/octet-stream");
    filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, "form-data; name=\"updateFile\"; filename=\"" + archive + "\"");
    QFile *file = new QFile(archive);
    file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    filePart.setBodyDevice(file);
    file->setParent(multiPart);  // To ensure the file object is deleted properly
    multiPart->append(filePart);

    // Send the POST request with multipart data
    QNetworkReply *reply = manager.post(request, multiPart);
    multiPart->setParent(reply);  // To ensure the multipart object is deleted properly

    QObject::connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished,  [=]() {
        qDebug() << "Response Headers:" << reply->rawHeaderPairs();
        if (reply->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            qDebug() << "Network Error:" << reply->errorString();
        }
        UploadResult(reply);
    });
}
```

Executing this code seems to not be able to send either the text input fields or the file input.

When I run the request from Postman like this:

[image]

There are no issues. File get's uploaded and all looks fine. However I am unable to replicate the post request with Qt.

Why is that, where is my mistake ?

Comment: Can you trim this down to an [mre]? It is a lot of code that has nothing to do with your file upload. Also, can you intercept the HTTP request and compare it to the one Postman sends?

Comment: Looks like the server is unable to read any of the fields because it returns:

{"message":"The update file field is required. (and 5 more errors)","errors":{"updateFile":["The update file field is required."],"os":["The os field is required."],"major":["The major field is required."],"minor":["The minor field is required."],"patch":["The patch field is required."],"build":["The build field is required."]}} Which is basically saying these fields are not present. Which as you can see is not true. Testing from Postman works, from Qt it does not.

Comment: So, obvious next step: what _is_ your client sending? Spin up something stupid like netcat in listen mode and just look at the HTTP request being sent.

Comment: As a random guess, `"form-data; name=\"" + params[i]` doesn't look like it can or should work.

Comment: I was thinking about that part too. How should I make them ?

Comment: from memory: `QString("...%1...").arg(params[i])`

Comment: Connect all the signals of the objects to debug print lambdas. That's really the step 1. Then you should see what happens.